# Unable to create react application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend

i keep trying to create a react application, am usually successful until it gets to when to create the app, then i receive an error on the command prompt showing me:
[[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGUU0.png)

Comment: try `npx create-react-app learn-react` on a new folder

Comment: Do npm cache clear and try again

Answer (score 1):

more than likely a local caching issue. try running ‘npm cache clean --force’ then try again